# How to get the nextPageToken value from the objects method?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm able to use the Google-supplied code example at [Google\Cloud\Storage\Bucket](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.32.0/storage/bucket?method=objects) and get the list of returned object names. The code indicates the returned object should also contain a reference to the `nextPageToken` value so I can page through a large number of objects.

I've not been able to find any reference in the docs or in any help forum as to how to access this value.

Comment: Have you tired just listing? I had thought the iterator automatically paged as needed behind the scenes.

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough, it looks like you're correct and just listing the items does return all of them, without the need to access the nextpageToken. This behavior is at odds with the PHP API documentation though that indicates a max of 1000 records will be returned by default and the example code shows a request for the nextPageToken field as well, which is why I was struggling to find out how to access that token to page the results. Do you know of a way to request updates to the API docs to avoid this confusion in the future?

Comment: You must include `nextPageToken` in the fields parameter E.g.
`$objects = $bucket->objects([
    'fields' => 'items/name,nextPageToken'
]);` otherwise it will only return 1000.

Comment: @nick ok but how to get the value next ?